# Change website title

Tags: html, title

I am using a program to make a website, but this program automatically adds some text to the website title. I can add codes to the head of the page that may be able to change the title. Does someone know what code I could use?

I can change the title in the files manually, but that's alot of work for a website with almost 400 pages... :(

`<title>Fun Dippers - UNREGISTERED VERSION</title>`

needs to be changed to

`<title>Fun Dippers - Nederlandse Tip-Site</title>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your assumption is correct regarding your files:

> I can change the title in the files manually, but that's alot of work for a website with almost 400 pages... :(

1. Download the software [Sublime Text Editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/)
2. <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Open Folder</kbd> > select your projects folder
3. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (this does Find and replace in open files and folders)
4. Find: `"UNREGISTERED VERSION</title>"`
5. Replace: `"Nederlandse Tip-Site</title"`
6. <kbd>Replace</kbd>
7. File > Save All
8. Upvote haha

[image]

Comment: I will have to use filezilla or something i guess, i changed it all and saved, uploaded using that program and it's all unregistered again. :( Well, i'll try that tomorrow and i'll post back here with the results. Upvoted for now! :) EDIT upvote needs 15 reputation =\

Comment: If you use a 'web service' that hosts and maintains your website (like weebly) I wouldn't be surprised if they do this on their end. If that's the case you have no chance.

Comment: I use the uploader included with the program, so i think it checks for  'corrupted' files.. :(

Comment: so dont use the uploader...

Answer (score 0):

You got two options

- Use a  REGISTERED VERSION of the program
- If you have programming experience use some HTML parsing libraries and replace TITLE tag/content to automate 400 pages. Example: jtidy.sourceforge.net, jsoup.org

Comment: It is registered, but for a maximum amount of pages and no, I don't have alot of HTML experience, but i have the ability to add a code to the head, which will be added to all pages automatically.